# Есть ли событие on DOM Connected или способ отследить добавление узла на страницу?

Tags: javascript

Суть такова, создал я значит узел: `const node = document.createElement('node');`
он сейчас не на странице просто хранится в переменной. Прошло какое-то время и мне понадобилось его добавить на страницу: `document.body.appendChild(node);`
И вот в этот момент мне нужно выполнять какой-то код или другими словами отслеживать добовление этого элемента на страницу. Идеально было бы сделать вот так: `node.addEventListener('connect', () => console.log('connected'));`, но ничего подобного я не нашёл. Единственное что я нашёл это свойство `node.isConnected`.

Есть ли событие добавления узла на страницу или способ такое с генерировать и отследить ?

Придумал просто проверять при каждом `appendChild` этого узла `isConnected` и в случае `true` стрелять ему событие, может быть есть способ лучше ?

Comment: у контейнера можно установить [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) и отлавливать когда у него внутри что-то меняется.

Answer (score 1):

Есть - [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```js
// выбираем целевой элемент
var target = document.querySelector('#root');
 
// создаём экземпляр MutationObserver
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  if(mutations[0].type === 'childList')
    console.info('Что-то случилось :)');
});
 
// конфигурация нашего observer:
var config = {childList: true, characterData: true };
 
// передаём в качестве аргументов целевой элемент и его конфигурацию
observer.observe(target, config);

let i = 0;
document.querySelector('#addNode').addEventListener('click', e => target.appendChild((e = document.createElement('div'), e.innerHTML = 'Text #' + ++i, e)));
```

```html
<div id='root'></div>
<input type='button' id='addNode' value='Добавить узел' />
```

---

Есть ещё [события на тему мутаций](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events), но их использовать не нужно, ибо Deprecated.